# composer require laravelcollective html 'doesnt download dependancy

Tags: php, html, laravel-5, composer-php, laravelcollective

[Please see when When I run composer install](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yut4W.png) please assist,

I am new to laravel and I cannot download dependency for laravelcollective/html  ... I am using laravel 5.5.13

I want to require laravelcollective/html

however I face the following problems.

1. when I run : `composer require "laravelcollective/html:5.2.*"`,

[I get the below mentioned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Me9Qd.png)(similarly when I run composer update ) :

```
C:\Users\MALULEKE\Desktop\lara_proj\shops>composer require "laravelcollective/html:5.2.*"
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested package laravelcollective/html could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability> for more details.

Read <https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.

C:\Users\MALULEKE\Desktop\lara_proj\shops>composer require "laravelcollective/html:5.2.*"
```

below is my composer.json relative to my project's work (not from composer/roaming, I am not even sure which is it I must use, please help )

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.0.0",
        "fideloper/proxy": "~3.3",
        "laravel/framework": "5.5.*@dev",
        "laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
        "laravelcollective/html":"~5.3.@dev"

    },
    "require-dev": {
        "filp/whoops": "~2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~6.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": [
            ]
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "optimize-autoloader": true

    }
}
```

Comment: So which version you need `5.2.*` or `~5.3.@dev`? You can't have both at the same time. It is a fundamental limitation of composer.

Comment: 5.3 ... I would love any v5 possibly

Comment: Well, if you need 5.3, an attempt to install `"laravelcollective/html:5.2.*"` makes no sense to me. Anyway you already have v5.3 in `composer.json`, so just `composer install` it.

Comment: I just added an image depicting what I get when I run composer install ... (**on the first line of the post **)... **It says package manifest generated successfully**, however I cannot see installed laravelcollective in vendor folder ...

Comment: If you are using Laravel 5.5, you should also be using version 5.5 for this package....

Comment: I just changed from 5.3.@dev to 5.5.@dev : No change still I get what is on the attached image and no dependency is added to vendor folder.

Comment: Either delete the composer.lock and `composer install` again,  or run `composer update` as the message suggests.

Comment: now I get an error mentioned above with problem 1 and problem 2

Comment: I have deleted composer.lock , after when I run composer install or update I get an error, see attached image, on the second link above

Comment: and my composer.lock  is not coming back after deleting it...

Answer (score 1):

Try running `composer require laravelcollective/html` which will install the latest version of LaravelCollective packages for you.

Answer (score 0):

I have decided to use AngularJS as my front end.

Note that this solution may not be suitable for everyone, and with this solution, problems may arrive in future, due to the need for other composer requirements, such as authentication dependencies that my be needed.